# fabric.js: adjusting the size of the controls of a modified polygon, v1.7.22 vs v2.7.0

Tags: javascript

I am upgrading from fabric.js v1.7.22 to v2.7.0. My app supports programmatic and/or graphical modification of polygons (e.g., changing position of one or more vertices). Under v1.7.22, the control size could be recalculated by calling obj.SetCoords(), but this does not seem to work under v2.7.0.

To see this, run the snippet web page with either version of fabric.js. The web page initially will show a polygon with the controls, as expected:

[image: before polygon change]

Using v1.7.22, clicking the "change" button will change a polygon point and (ignoring the fact that the polygon is not in the correct location, a v1 problem requiring some fiddling) the controls will become larger to match the new size of the polygon:

[image: v1.7.22 after polygon change]

Using v2.7.0, the polygon will be in the right place (no need to fiddle any more, thanks!) but the controls have not changed:

[image: v2.7.0 after polygon change]

What code mod is needed to update the size of the controls for the modified polygon in v2.7.0?

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.7.22/fabric.min.js"></script>
<!-- <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/2.7.0/fabric.min.js"></script> -->
</head>

<body onload="init()">
<canvas id="c" width="200" height="200" style="border:1px solid red"></canvas>
<button onclick="change()">change</button>

<script>
var canvas, poly;
var points1 = [{x:-30, y:30}, {x:30, y:30}, {x:0, y:-30}];
var points2 = [{x:-60, y:60}, {x:30, y:30}, {x:0, y:-30}];

function init(){
  canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
  poly = new fabric.Polygon(points1,
  {left: 50, top: 50, strokeWidth: 2, stroke: 'cyan', objectCaching: false});
  canvas.add(poly);
}

function change(x, y){
    poly.set({left: 50, top: 50, points: points2});
    poly._calcDimensions();
    poly.setCoords();
    canvas.renderAll();
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So i made an answer that is probably not what you want, but i think is useful to get started with a proper solution.

So as you see in my fiddle, the controls change correctly.
I changed on purpose the point that gets modified in order to get the worst effect possible.

The point is that you would need to figure out how to not make the triangle not move on the canvas.

In order to do so you should calculate the absolute position of a point to the canvas and the set the next position of the triangle mantaining that fixed.

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/2.7.0/fabric.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body onload="init()">
<canvas id="c" width="200" height="200" style="border:1px solid red"></canvas>
<button onclick="change()">change</button>
<button onclick="change2()">change2</button>

<script>
var canvas, poly;
var points1 = [{x:-130, y:-70}, {x:-70, y:-70}, {x:-120, y:-130}];
var points2 = [{x:-130, y:-70}, {x:-70, y:-70}, {x:-180, y:-170}];

function init(){
  canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
  poly = new fabric.Polygon(points1,
  {left: 50, top: 50, strokeWidth: 2, stroke: 'cyan', objectCaching: false});
  canvas.add(poly);
}

function change(x, y){
    poly.initialize(points2, { left: poly.left, top: poly.top });
    poly.setCoords();
    canvas.renderAll();
}

function change2(x, y){
    var matrix = poly.calcTransformMatrix();
    var point1 = new fabric.Point(points1[0].x, points1[0].y);
    point1 = point1.subtract(poly.pathOffset);
    // newP is where is now point[0] on the canvas;
    var newP = fabric.util.transformPoint(point1, matrix);
    poly.initialize(points2);
    // now poly is initialized with new dimensions. Where is p[0] now?
    var newOffset = poly.pathOffset;
    var point1 = new fabric.Point(points1[0].x, points1[0].y);
    point1 = point1.subtract(newOffset);
    point1.x /= poly.width;
    point1.y /= poly.height;
    // let's set the polygon's position to where p[0] was
    // giving as anchor point the relative position of where p[0] is now with the new configuration
    poly.setPositionByOrigin(newP, point1.x + 0.5, point1.y + 0.5);
    poly.setCoords();
    canvas.renderAll();
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

EDIT:
i spent a bit of time and added the change2 button that handle the change pedantically but explaining what is going on.
I think this is the right way to go provided you can find out a point in the polygon that is not changing and that you can use as anchor point.

Comment: Is there a reason the full initialize() has to be called, instead of this, which just resetting the width, height, and pathOffset:  `function change(x, y){
        var calcDims;
        poly.set({left: 50, top: 50, points: points2});
        calcDim = poly._calcDimensions();
        poly.width = calcDim.width;
        poly.height = calcDim.height;
        poly.pathOffset = {
            x: calcDim.left + poly.width / 2,
            y: calcDim.top + poly.height / 2
        };
        poly.setCoords();
        canvas.renderAll();
    }
`

Comment: no there is not a reason. The full initializa is shorter and more or less does that. How much more stuff does initialize do?

Comment: It does a callSuper() with the passed-in options, which could lead to side-effects, depending on what that black-box call does. So I think it's safer and more clear to call the resizing code explicitly.

Comment: well depends. Untill this is a supported feature, one way or the other is still a blackbox. The more important thing i think is keeping the position of the object steady when changing points.

Comment: Agreed. I was under the impression that the position was steady under 2.7.0 but I'll work out the details in my project code, beyond the test code we've been discussing. I'm going to accept this answer and I'll get back to you if there are other issues. Thanks!